# jQuery: how do I position an image?

Tags: jquery, css

I have this:

```
function startLoad(object_id) {
$j('div#'+object_id).addClass('currently-loading');
var con = $j('div#overlay');
var img = $j('div#loadimg');
var tab = $j('table.app');
con.height(tab.height() - 30);
con.width(tab.width());
con.css('display', 'block');

img.css('margin-left', (con.width() / 2 - 36) + 'px');
img.css('margin-top', (con.height() / 2 - 36) + 'px');
//alert( (con.width() / 2 - 36)+" "+(con.height() / 2 - 36))
```

}

and when i uncomment the alert, it shows the correct dimensions...
I have tried left, margin-left, both with and without the px.
(some for top)

what am I doing wrong?

everything works, except img is in the top left corner of the div that contains it.

Comment: In these kind of cases when you're trying to find the right style attributes, it helps to alter it in firebug to get it pixel perfect to find out exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just posted an answer for the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214404/jquery-overlay-loading-bar-div/3214831#3214831).

### [[See it in action](http://jsbin.com/eficu4/2/)]

**HTML**

```
<div id="overlay">
  <img src="http://www.sanbaldo.com/wordpress/wp-content/bigrotation2.gif" 
    id="img-load" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#overlay { 
  display:none; 
  position:absolute; 
  background:#fff; 
}
#img-load { 
  position:absolute; 
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$t = $("#table"); // CHANGE it to the table's id you have

$("#overlay").css({
  opacity : 0.5,
  top     : $t.offset().top,
  width   : $t.outerWidth(),
  height  : $t.outerHeight()
});

$("#img-load").css({
  top  : ($t.height() / 2),
  left : ($t.width() / 2)
});
```

Then when you're loading things you just say:

```
$("#overlay").fadeIn();
```

And when you finished

```
$("#overlay").fadeOut();
```

Comment: so, i changed my img modifications to this   

 $t = $j('div#overlay');
 
 img.css({
  top  : ($t.width() / 2 - 36),
  left : ($t.height() / 2 - 36)
  
 });

i really like the syntax, but my image is still in the top left =\

Comment: as it turns out, I was using the wrong id name. lol.
anyway... now i just need to fix my math, so its centered.

 alert(con.width()+" "+con.height()+"--"+(con.width() / 2 - 36)+" "+(con.height() / 2 - 36))

for whatever reason, dividing by two doesn't mean half?

Comment: your math looks fine. Make sure to use `position:absolute` for both `#overlay` and `#loadimg`.

Comment: also use `tab.outerWidth()` and height because it includes padding, while `width()` doesn't. But as i said, **see my answer**  and change accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

for using left and top you need to position the image absolutely.

```
position:absolute;
```

also the container element should have position:relative; set on it

use this and try top, left instead of margin-top and margin-left in your code;

Comment: No, he could use `position: relative` too.